# Automatise Adduser for Windows Active Directory 2008

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I would like to add a lot of users into my Active Directory Users Group based on a csv with specifics informations like phone numero, email, job ...

I look around the internet and found a "method" using powershell. But, it's always to add basic infos like Name, Surname, Login and password.

Is there a webpage referencing the New-ADuser cmd ?

I found something on this website 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/pascals/archive/2013/08/09/cr-233-er-des-utilisateurs-de-test-dans-ad-avec-un-mini-script-powershell.aspx

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try `help -full new-aduser` in Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the Quest AD cmdlets which makes easier the AD manipulation.

You can download the cmdlets from [here](http://ss64.com/ps/quest.html).

You can also add phone number, webpage, etc. by default, or you can use the -IncludedProperties for addition.

[Here](http://ss64.com/ps/new-qaduser.html) is the syntax for the new user creation.